# Microsoft UEFI-Compliant System not showing in Device Manager

Tags: windows, windows-10, uefi, gpt

I installed Windows 10 Pro 64bit on a GPT SSD and started Windows on UEFI Firmware. When I go into Device Manager, I can't see System Firmware and Microsoft UEFI-Compliant System even when I showed hidden devices and scannned for hardware changes. Can someone explain?

Comment: Where are you getting the information that states those two items should be displayed in Device Manager? _(I have a UEFI motherboard using UEFI boot and I've never come across either in Device Manager)_

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.